# Error when trying to run hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have installed `hive(2.1.1)` on `Hadoop(2.7.3)` in `aws ec2 Ubuntu 14.04` instance.

Earlier I was able start hive by just typing commands **`start-all.sh` and `hive`** now when I try to do it again, I am getting the following error:

```
_Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot create directory /tmp/hive/hduser/77c5347f-bcdb-452b-9a99-86f45827933a. Name node is in safe mode.
Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3895)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot create directory /tmp/hive/hduser/77c5347f-bcdb-452b-9a99-86f45827933a. Name node is in safe mode.
Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3895)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:558)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3000)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2970)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createPath(SessionState.java:732)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:655)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:563)
        ... 9 more
```

How can I solve it?

(I also tried **`hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`**)

Comment: check the free disk space on hdfs.

Comment: Thank you @philantrovert my disk space was low so i freed up some space and able to start hive smoothly

Answer (score 2):

My **disk space was low** and **my hdfs was full** so I cleaned hdfs and was able to start hive smoothly.

I used the following commands:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
hdfs dfs -rm -R directory/name/which/contains/waste/files
```

Special Thanks for @philantrovert :)

Comment: you might want to use `hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash /hdfs/path/to/dir` if the directory contains data that you don't want at all. Otherwise all the deleted files will accumulate under you `/user/<username>/.Trash` dir